# Android: re-starting Timer fails

Tags: android

I'm trying to download some data of a url every X minutes. This is run from a Service.

I have the following in my Service class:

```
public class CommandsService extends Service {
    public String errormgs;

// in miliseconds
static final long DELAY = 60*1000;

public Timer timer;

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    TimerTask task= new TimerTask (){
        public void run(){
            //do what you needs.
            processRemoteFile();

            // schedule new timer
            // following line gives error
            timer.schedule(this, DELAY);
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, 0);

    return START_STICKY;

} 
 //....
}
```

Runs fine a first time, but when I try to "schedule" the timer a second time with the DELAY, LogCat complains:

"TimeTask scheduled already"

How could I re-schedule the Timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TimerTask` is a single use item. It can't be rescheduled or reused; you'll need to create new instances on the fly as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public class CommandsService extends Service {
    public String errormgs;

    // in miliseconds
    static final long DELAY = 60*1000;

    public Thread thread;

    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
            public void run() {
                while (<condition>) {
                    //do what you needs.
                    processRemoteFile();

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
    //...
}
```